# Pushing the mainActivity to the side When the Navigation Drawer Opens

Tags: android

Currently, when the navigation drawer in my app opens, it appears on top of the mainActivity view.

My question being, is it possible to animate the mainActivity view so that the left side of said view matches the right side of the navigation drawer when it  opens?

Comment: I hope my post helps. Please take a look and ask me if you have any question. I just want to confirm, that is what you were asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is (almost) always possible. But i think it is a bad idea, as it will not follow the ui [guidelines from google](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#) for an android app.

However if you really want to do it, you have two options :

1. Easy. When the drawer is open start animation on the rest of the layout, and do the opposite animation when the drawer is closed. It is less effort, but probably poor result.
2. Implement your own drawer. You will be able to have the perfect animation and behavior you desire. In this case you probably want to use fragment. The main fragment will be the content and another fragment will be the drawer. When you need to do it, you can animate both fragment with a translation to "open" your drawer.

You can read more about animation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is setX() of your main_content in the Activity

my_activity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content_rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/material_grey_100">
        <include
            layout="@layout/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MyActivity java file

```
    mDrawerToggle =
            new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,
                    R.string.drawer_close) {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                    float width = drawerView.findViewById(R.id.main_header_rl).getWidth();
                    final int movement= (int) (width * slideOffset);
                    findViewById(R.id.main_content_rl).setX(movement);
                    super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                }
            };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Where `main_header_rl` is the id of my `header_navigation_drawer`

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_header_rl"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```